# tkinter text box ignoring index

Tags: python, tkinter, text

I am trying to create a simple 4 line text box where I can update each of the 4 lines independently. The documentation says I can do this by setting the index in the insert method, but whatever I put in there gets ignored..! The example below puts each string after the previous one, not on separate lines. Can anyone point me to where I may be going wrong..?

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry('400x200')
textbox = tk.Text(window, width=20, height=4)
textbox.grid(row=0, column=0)

textbox.insert("1.1", "Line 1")
textbox.insert("2.2", "Line 2")
textbox.insert("3.3", "Line 3")
textbox.insert("4.4", "Line 4")

window.mainloop()
```

Output is "Line1Line2Line3Line4", where I would expect each to be on it's own line).

Comment: It is because the specified indexes are beyond the end of the current content, so they are inserted at the end of the current content.  If you just want 4 line of entries independent to each others, better use 4 `Entry` boxes instead of single `Text` widget.

Comment: Try adding `textbox.insert("\n \n  \n   \n    ")` just after the `textbox.grid(...)`

Comment: Amazing, thank you both. Not to be picky, but adding textbox.insert("1.0", "\n \n  \n   \n    ") fixed it.